# What practical problems in the world can I apply Laplace Transforms to solve a $2^{nd}$ order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, applications

Kirchoff's Law for circuits is the most obvious answer... but other than that, I haven't been able to find any examples where Laplace Transforms can be used to solve a model of **interesting** real life examples.

If anyone has any examples of some ideas to look up, or any links/books to read on this area, then that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit ; see in particular https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#Laplace_domain

Comment: Laplace transform is a method used to solve 2nd order ODEs, not modelling it.

Comment: @CheeHan Indeed, I have amended the question.

Comment: The Laplace transform works with circuit problems because the underlying ODEs are constant-coefficient equations. So you could ask what other situations are modeled by second-order constant-coefficient linear equations. One such class of physical problems are those concerning physical oscillators, the simplest example of which is an ideal spring, which is governed by Hooke's law. Introducing damping gives rise to equations of the form $y'' + py' + qy = f$, where $q>0$ and $p\geq 0$. In the small-angle approximation you could also model a simple pendulum with such equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note here:

> Differential Equation $\to$ **Laplace Transform** $\to$ Algebraic Equation

So basically its unifying two different branches of mathematics. As far as I have known (I am not a Physics guy) L.T. is applied to  circuit studies as you have mentioned. Like Fourier Transform, L.T. is also used in signal processing. For a more detailed reference you can check [this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-real-world-applications-of-Laplace-transform-especially-in-computer-science) out.

Answer (score 0):

Automobile suspensions.  What happens when you drive over a speed bump?